# C# maintain type safety when using GCHandle to pin array and pass to C function

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I have the following method signature:

```
[DllImport("CLibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "deduce", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
unsafe static extern int Deduce(int pItems, int pParams, bool pEntropy, IntPtr pRank, IntPtr pWeight, IntPtr pResults);
```

C header:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int deduce(int p_items, int p_params, bool p_entropy, float* p_rank, float* p_weight, float* p_results)
```

I call the function as follows:

```
// dist, weight, results are float[]
GCHandle p1 = GCHandle.Alloc(dist, GCHandleType.Pinned);
GCHandle p2 = GCHandle.Alloc(weight, GCHandleType.Pinned);
GCHandle p3 = GCHandle.Alloc(results, GCHandleType.Pinned);

int ok = Deduce(items_C, params_C, true, p1.AddrOfPinnedObject(), p2.AddrOfPinnedObject(), p3.AddrOfPinnedObject());

p1.Free();
p2.Free();
p3.Free();
```

It works fine. What I don't like is that `dist`, `weight`, and `results` are no longer type safe. They're of type `float`.

I can't see how to have type safety if I use the `GCHandle` approach (which is apparently the most efficient way of pinning).

Is there a better option / way to maintain type safety?

Comment: If their (original, I assume) type is `float`, why don't you pass them as such? Is the call to `Deduce()` async or on a separate thread where the calling function goes away before `Deduce` returns?

Comment: Yes, they are floats. It's a synchronous call in the same thread. Are you suggesting I just used `fixed` to pin the arrays? I prefer not to do that.

Comment: If you are passing floats to a function expecting pointers to int, the C code will halt and catch fire.

Comment: What's your C function signature (in the header, not the P/Invoke bit that you have for it)?

Comment: I'm passing pointers to float[] to a C function that is expecting float*. The code works fine.

Comment: You are helping too much, just let the pinvoke marshaller do the job.  Change float* to float[].  Either way it is up to you to ensure that the arrays are sized correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant do you mean I don't need to use `GCHandle` but can simply pass the float and it will be auto pinned for me?

Comment: @IamIC Yes, `GCHandle` is really the heavyweight way of doing this.

Comment: So, this? `unsafe static extern int Deduce(int pItems, int pParams, bool pEntropy, float[] pRank, float[] pWeight, float[] pResults);` Called: `Deduce(items_C, params_C, true, dist, weight, results)`

Comment: @IamIC Yes, that looks about right. Make sure your arrays have the right number of elements when you pass them in.

Comment: The lengths are carefully managed. I tested and it's all working fine. Thanks much! I assume `GCHandle` is only needed if an array was passed into multiple managed functions.